# Ambiguity in synthesis (crystallization)

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, experimental-chemistry

A paper says the following,

> Dichloroglyoxime was prepared by chlorination of glyoxime in 10 % HCl at 0 deg C and crystallized from toluene.

When they say "crystallized from toluene" do they unambiguously mean recrystallized from boiling toluene at standard pressure? Thermally these compounds are unstable and instead of a white nice product I've ended up with a purple one much to my dismay and I'm not sure what actually causes the purple.

I've had problems with this synthesis because the $^1$H NMR always shows more than one oxime environment.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but would you be so kind to post full synthesis? It is relevant to one of my interests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  This could also mean applying a vacuum to the toluene-dichloroglyoxime solution, and letting the solvent evaporate-away at room temperature.